# Are the probabilities of 2 events equal if A implies B and B implies A?

Tags: probability

I'm trying to understand a bit of math in a computer graphics textbook. The bit I'm stuck on is where they say - if we have a random variable X with some density function, and we transform the samples drawn from X using $Y_i = y(X_i)$, then, assuming y is one-to-one, then its derivative must be either strictly greater than zero or strictly less that zero (this part I get), which implies that

\begin{align}
Pr\{Y <= y(x)\} = Pr\{X <= x\}
\end{align}

I can see how this works if the answer to my title question is yes, but I can't find anything stating this exactly. Does the iff condition mean that the two events are equivalent, and that's why the probabilities are necessarily equal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, because in that case $A$ and $B$ are the same set (I assume you mean $\omega\in A$ implies $\omega\in B$ and conversely $\omega\in B$ implies $\omega\in A$... which is precisely $A=B$).

If you are not yet convinced, let's recall some of the theory. One begins by working in a probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$, where $\Omega$ is a set (usually thought of as possible results for an experiment), $\mathcal{F}\subseteq \mathcal{P}(\Omega)$ is a $\sigma$-algebra, a special family of sets satisfying some properties whose members we will call events and a function $\mathbb{P}:\mathcal{F}\to [0,1]$ satisfying some properties which we call the probability measure. Recall that $\mathbb{P}$ is a function, so for each set $A\in\mathcal{F}$ one has that there is a unique real number in $[0,1]$ assigned to it by $\mathbb{P}$, which we denote by $\mathbb{P}(A)$.

Now, let's look at the sets in more detail. Suppose $\varphi$ to be strictly increasing (the other case is similar). Random variables are functions $X:(\Omega, \mathcal{F}) \to (\mathbb{R}, \beta(R))$ which are measurable. That is, functions satisfying $\{\omega\in\Omega : X(\omega)\in B\}\in\mathcal{F}$ for every Borel set $B$; in particular both $\{\omega \in \Omega : Y(\omega)\leq \varphi(x)\}, \{\omega \in \Omega : X(\omega)\leq x\}$ are measurable so we will be able to calculate their probability. The only thing that remains to be seen is that $\{\omega \in \Omega : Y(\omega)\leq \varphi(x)\}=\{\omega \in \Omega : X(\omega)\leq x\}$ and then their probabilities will coincide since $\mathbb{P}$ is a function and those are different ways of expressing the same set, the same element in the function's domain. This indeed holds because $Y=\varphi(X)$ and both $\varphi$ and $\varphi^{-1}$ are strictly increasing so they preserve inequalities.